# when i try to convert .htaccess file to nginx i am getting an error that i cant fic

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

```
`map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default 1M;
    image/jpg 1y;
    image/jpeg 1y;
    image/gif 1y;
    image/png 1y;
    text/css 1M;
    text/html 1M;
    application/pdf 1M;
    text/x-javascript 1M;
    application/x-shockwave-flash 1M;
    image/x-icon 1y;
}
server {
    server_name example.com;
    expires $expires;
    location ~ "^/([^\.]+)$" {
        try_files $uri /$1.php$is_args$args;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~ "!^admin") {
        rewrite ^/profile/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}profile.php?code=$1 last;
    }
    rewrite ^/company/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}company-profile.php?code=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/listings/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}target-listing.php?code=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/ebook/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}ebook.php?code=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/promotion/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}template-default.php?code=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/blog/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}blog-details.php?row=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/event/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}event-details.php?row=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/product/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}product-details.php?code=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/listing/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}listing-details.php?code=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/job/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}jobs/job-details.php?code=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/all-jobs/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}jobs/all-jobs.php?category=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/job-profile/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}jobs/job-profile.php?code=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/service-expert/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}service-experts/service-experts-profile.php?code=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/all-service-experts/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}service-experts/all-service-experts.php?category=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/news-detail/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}news/news-details.php?code=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/news-all/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}news/news-all.php?category=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/place/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}places/place-details.php?code=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/all-listing/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}all-listing.php?category=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/all-listing/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}all-listing.php?category=$1&&subcategory=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/all-products/([^/]*)$ /%{ENV:BASE_PATH}all-products.php?category=$1 last;
}
```

when i try to convert my .htaccess to nginx i am getting an error

> "nginx: [emerg] directive "rewrite" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:148
> nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed"

please help